# AVAudioRecorder initial recording after APP restart is always silent / nill

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avaudiosession, avaudiorecorder

I have the following code for an AVAudioRecorder. The code works except for that the initial recording after the APP has been launched / restarted is always null / silent. Has anyone ever encountered a similar problem or do you see a bug in my code?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {
    var recordingSession:AVAudioSession!
    var audioRecorder:AVAudioRecorder!
    var player:AVAudioPlayer!
    var soundURL:URL!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        soundURL = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("record.m4a")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func Rcrd(_ sender: Any) {

        if audioRecorder == nil
        {

            let filename = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("record.m4a")

            let settings = [AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC), AVSampleRateKey: 1200, AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1, AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue]

            //Start audio recording
            do
            {
                audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: filename, settings: settings)
                audioRecorder.delegate = self
                audioRecorder.record()

                //buttonLabel.setImage(UIImage(named: "stopBtn.png"), for: .normal)
            }
            catch{
                displayAlert(title: "UPS!",message:NSLocalizedString("RcrdFl", comment: ""))
            }

        }
        else{
            //Stopping audio recording
            audioRecorder.stop()
            audioRecorder = nil

           let filename = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("record.m4a")

            do {
                player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: filename)
                player.play()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.description)
            }



        }
    }

    @IBAction func Ply(_ sender: Any) {
        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
            player.play()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.description)
        }
    }

    func getDirectory() -> URL
    {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentDirectory = paths[0]
        return documentDirectory
    }

    //Function that displats an alert
    func displayAlert(title:String,message:String)
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil ))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

If you have another working avudiorecorder please send it to me

Comment: lot of examples here: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=record

Comment: Thank you for the link :) But do you have any idea what might be wrong with my code?

Comment: check with this code have you a valid url or not `fileURL.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(&error)`

Comment: `let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)`

With this url, you may able to instantiate and play an instance of AVPlayer. try this

Comment: @Radonic if you can share sample project with audio you are trying to play I can help with problem in your code.

Comment: Thank you guys for the input, but I came up with a work around where I initiate and stop the initial recording before any other and that solved my problem :)